GDAL-info with Java bindings not working correctly
When making a gdalinfo call on a drone-photo via the GDAL java-bindings api, the resulting string is sometimes being cut-off prematurely. I.e. the last part of result is missing. However if I run the gdalinfo command from a command-line all the text is there. Here's my code:
 public static void getInfoFromSingleFile(){
    gdal.AllRegister();
    Vector vector = new Vector();
    vector.add("-json");
    InfoOptions infoOptions = new InfoOptions(vector);
    Dataset dataset = gdal.Open("ArialPhoto.JPG");
    String gdalInfo = gdal.GDALInfo(dataset, infoOptions);
    System.out.println(gdalInfo);
}

From the java console output it's obvious that the JSON string is corrupted, as it ends like:
 "eo:bands":[
  {
    "name":"b1",
    "description":"Red"

If I run gdalinfo -json ArialPhoto.JPG from the command-line, the JSON output is correctly closed:
 "eo:bands":[
  {
    "name":"b1",
    "description":"Red"
  },
  {
    "name":"b2",
    "description":"Green"
  },
  {
    "name":"b3",
    "description":"Blue"
  }
]

}
Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Since my first post, I had the opportunity to try out a set of photos taking with a different drone, and they all passed flawlessly. Hence the conclusion for now is, that the original photo(S) were somehow corrupted.
